# search int number in text file

Tags: c++, text

I have a text file.
All values stored in it are integers.
When I compare the number I search for and the number stored in the text file, the result is incorrect!

My code:

```
ifstream infile ("h1.txt");
if (!infile)

{
    cout << "Can't open file" << endl;
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
int n;
infile >> n;
while(!infile.eof()){
    if (n!=search)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
    infile>>n;
}
```

Why does the compiler consider the result false even when `n` is equal to search?

Comment: please fix your awful indentation

Comment: The error handling in the loop header is incorrect. Stream can fail for other reasons than `eof`. More idiomatic and much simpler: `while( infile >> n ) { /* loop body */ }`

Answer (score 2):

You are only reading the first number from the file whether is correct or not. The execution of a function ends when the code reaches a `return`.

Comment: thank you Ervin, you're right but the problem still even i replace return with bool variable !!

Answer (score -1):

I Solved the problem, number stores the last value only, i.e the value of number 
if the search found will be as the search hence, the condition will be true the 
bool value will be also true but when the file read the value not equal the search the compiler will entered in else section also and make the bool variable false although the search founded!(especially when the search number found in the beginning of the file), so I solved it by remove else and make the bool variable true if and only if the search is founded in the file. hope you understand

Comment: I'm not sure, but are you saying you did something like [this](https://pastebin.com/Gm1VXj1y)?